# JS has object wrappers to let me check primitive's "property" exists or not, how do I let TS work like that?

Tags: javascript, typescript, primitive

The return value of [XMLValidator](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser).validate is either `true` or `ValidationError` (which is not exactly correct, check my update), which has `err` property.

```
validate(  xmlData: string,  options?: validationOptionsOptional): true | ValidationError
```

Because javascript uses object wrappers for boolean primitive I can just check whether the err property exists or not to see if the validation succeeds.

```
const result = XMLValidator.validate(message)
if (result.err) { // How do I make it work in ts?
   console.log(`invalid XML)
} else {
  console.log(`XML)
}
```

But typescript won't let me do that, it will complain `Property 'err' does not exist on type 'true'`

I don't like the idea of checking the return type first because I feel it is wordy and there is no return value type definition actually (check my update). How do I write the ts code here as **concise** as my js code?

--- update ---

I further check [validator.js code](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser/blob/master/src/validator.js#L388)

```
const isValid = validateAttributeString(attrStr, options);
if (isValid !== true) {
   return getErrorObject(...);
}
...

function getErrorObject(code, message, lineNumber) {
  return {
    err: {
      code: code,
      msg: message,
      line: lineNumber.line || lineNumber,
      col: lineNumber.col,
    },
  };
}
```

So it seems that I can only do `if (typeof result == "boolean")` here but I hope there is any "general" solution to my question.

Comment: Maybe simply checking for `result === true` for the successful case? Is this good enough for you? There won't be any `typeof` check.

Comment: Actually I was thinking maybe `if (typeof result == "boolean")  ...`  But I feel this is one of cases when ts is wordy while js is good enough. So I asked the question to see if others have some better idea.

Comment: Why do you want to check for a boolean if TS assures you it will be `true | ValidationError`? I think using a `typeof` is a little bit of overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that TypeScript won't let you access a property that it doesn't know can exist on a variable's type. If that type is a union, then the property must exist on *all* members of that union before TypeScript will let you access it.

But it is possible to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of a variable through various methods. For example, you could first check if the value is `true`, and if it's not then TypeScript will narrow the union down to just `ValidationError`.

Normally, another option would be to [use the `in` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing), but in this case the union doesn't only contain object types so TypeScript won't allow it.

You could also [define a custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) (or use one provided by the library, if one exists), but for a simple case like this that seems like it's probably a bit too much work for what you want.

As the TypeScript documentation I linked to details, there are other ways of narrowing types too. Checking the result of the `typeof` operator, like you've mentioned, is another one of those methods.

This example just declares that a typeguard exists, rather than implementing one, but here's how you could use each of those approaches to narrow the type of your `result` variable:

```js
declare type ValidationError = { err: unknown };
declare function isValidationError(val: unknown): val is ValidationError;

declare const XMLValidator: {
  validate(message: unknown): true | ValidationError
};

const message = 'test message';

const result = XMLValidator.validate(message)

// You can check first if the result is `true`
if (result === true) {
  // Handle success
} else {
  // Then the `else` branch knows it much be a `ValidationError`
  console.error(result.err);
}

// Normally allowed, but not in this case. Error:
// Type 'true | ValidationError' is not assignable to type 'object'
if ('err' in result) {
  console.error(result.err)
}

if (isValidationError(result)) {
  console.error(result.err);
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAXAngBwQNShAlsKiOA9gHYCiMMRM8AvPAN7wiUBc8AriQNYlEDuJeAF8A3AChQkWAgBmXMIVLwcAZyy58S8pWoAKAG7Z2XXgJIBKdkYgrV8DXgLEdVGBMnhoceGFKrEeAANAFkAGUctanYGcXh4GydEED0AWxBVVSgAcxATHj5BKyQYDgQAHwdsJJcKN3ExcXE-EgD4dMychHoAcmS2jqzcno8WtrhVDghA+lCI6qiYADpErRTBrosmgHpt+ABNIg5fKCEwAAtwbnhZHBg2nFkkS-gJqcC1eAADRFKQL-Ej3geje0zotHovzKFkYcXgu3gAAlTsAIAhJmAwBlVA1mBBVAhYvEEQAVS5CRAvL4gfH-eAAIxgpwu8DM-HsOECqQ4LPpCCg30izlIdWoAPiYyIaKWLDcIIy7xllAsEmEOz2ADlqKlsBBkPBdQIQMAADQMjiBPgfCnnT5gKAEpbwUUwVjiUloBB9P7wSpC7Qunp2eBWg2ZHDZEhQelopBEJCe+A9Ij0gBW4EQPUBTz0PVlQZwQlBiBhRN8-ilICVcuL1a2auzwLU-tquhg8sm0wspbhkulsv0tdlKoa4iAA)

---

Though they're usually best avoided, another option available to you is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) via TypeScript's `as` keyword.

The reason why these are best avoided is because you're telling TypeScript to treat a type as though it were something else. So you can compromise type safety by doing this.

```js
console.error((result as ValidationError).err);
```

However, in cases where you understand what's going on better than the TypeScript compiler does, this is the tool you can use to provide more information to it.

Personally, I find it's a helpful approach to always leave a comment explaining why a type assertion has been used, mentioning any assumptions that its safety is based on.

Also, in this case, using a type assertion to check that property doesn't narrow the type of the `result` variable, so this approach might not be exactly what you need.

Comment: I guess narrowing is as close as I can get. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're checking for existence of a property `.err` by probing its value. Since probing non-existent properties is an error in TypeScript, and `.err` only *conditionally* exists on the value (i.e., it exists only if the value is `ValidationError` object), you get a compilation error.

Of course, if TypeScript knows that the value is not just `true | ValidationError` but exactly `ValidationError`, then it won't show you any compilation errors, because that's going to be a guarantee that `.err` exists:

```
if (value === true) {
  // type of `value` is `true` (yes, I said type)
} else {
  // type of `value` is `ValidationError`
  // `value.err` should be accessible without compilation errors
}
```

```
if (value instanceof Object) {
  // type of `value` is `ValidationError`
} else {
  // type of `value` is `true` 
}
```